# Формирование документа для последующей печати на размеченном бланке

Tags: python, pil

Есть заранее существующий бланк.

В бланк нужно внести определенные поля: ФИО, Паспортные данные и т.п.

Бланк гос-образца (А4), печатается в типографии. Формировать бланк с заранее известными данными не получится.

Что требуется от меня:

Сформировать картинку (белый фон). Где в различных местах будут проставлены данные для полей. При печати в качестве бумаги будет подсунут бланк, в нужные поля которого подставятся данные (как печать грамот, грубо говоря).

Для решения задачи выбрал `Python` и библиотеку для работы с изображениями `PIL`.

У принтера может быть разный DPI, в основном 600 и 1200. Для этого нашел формулу для перевода ММ в PX с учетом DPI, реализовал функцию:

```
def mm_to_pixels(mm, dpi=600, round=True):
    _ = (mm * dpi) / 25.4  # 25.4 is number of millimeters in an inch
    return int(_) if round else _
```

Формирую холст:

```
canvas_size = (
    mm_to_pixels(210),
    mm_to_pixels(297),
)  # A4
image = Image.new('1', canvas_size, 1)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
```

Выбираю шрифт, размер подобрал методом тыка:

```
def get_font_size_for_dpi(dpi=600):
    if dpi == 300:
        return 32
    if dpi == 600:
        return 64
    if dpi == 1200:
        return 128
    return 64

font = ImageFont.truetype("FreeMono.ttf", get_font_size_for_dpi(600))
```

Наношу нужные данные на холст:

```
draw.text(
    (mm_to_pixels(0), mm_to_pixels(45)),
    "Пупкин Василий Иванович",
    font=font,
)

draw.text(
    (mm_to_pixels(43), mm_to_pixels(47)),
    "01.01.1990",
    font=font,
)
```

Сохраняю изображение:

```
image.save('600.png', 'PNG')
```

При печати, однако, все криво и косо. Костылить и делать какие-то поправки в пикселях на принтер не хочется, но, если не найду решения, буду.

Что я не учел?

Comment: я бы вообще смотрел в сторону работы с pdf.

Comment: В пдф можно обойтись без питона, он поддерживает текстовые поля. Прямо в ридере заполняете и печатайте.

Comment: В питоне я использую для бланков svg. Там подогнал под размер один раз и потом слова легко подставляются в нужные места, хоть с поворотом.

Comment: Всем спасибо! Выбрал pdf и reportlab.